# View matrix in opengl

Tags: opengl, matrix, linear-algebra

Sorry for my clumsy question.
But I don't know where I am wrong at creating view matrix.

I have the following code:

```
 createMatrix(vec4f(xAxis.x, xAxis.y, xAxis.z, dot(xAxis,eye)), 
 vec4f(  yAxis.x_, yAxis.y_, yAxis.z_, dot(yAxis,eye)), 
 vec4f(-zAxis.x_, -zAxis.y_, -zAxis.z_, -dot(zAxis,eye)), 
 vec4f(0, 0, 0, 1)); //column1, column2,...
```

I have tried to transpose it, but with no success.
I have also tried to use gluLookAt(...) with success.
At the reference page, I watched the remarks about the to-be-created matrix, and it seems the same as mine. Where I am wrong?

Comment: Maybe you can find something here: http://www.programmersheaven.com/2/world-view in section Creating the view matrix

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In openGl matrices are transposed in memory. So transpose the matrix is OK. But your code doesn't look correct.

So you are in OpenGl. OpenGl uses right handed coordinate system. And for RH is lookat function defined like this:

```
zaxis = normal(cameraPosition - cameraTarget)
xaxis = normal(cross(cameraUpVector, zaxis))
yaxis = cross(zaxis, xaxis)

 xaxis.x           yaxis.x           zaxis.x          0
 xaxis.y           yaxis.y           zaxis.y          0
 xaxis.z           yaxis.z           zaxis.z          0
-dot(xaxis, cameraPosition)  -dot(yaxis, cameraPosition)  -dot(zaxis, cameraPosition)  1
```

Especialy take care about `zaxis = normal(cameraPosition - cameraTarget)` because it is the only difference between RH and LH system.

**Save it transposed and that's it**

Comment: Still does not work. I can move the camera pos, but the rotation does not work correctly.(it looks like the world object rotates around of the orig instead of the camera.

Comment: @user5584 Interesting. And with the same inputs gluLookAt works? And if you say rotate you mean rotate camera target or multiply view matrix with rotation matrix? Does your rotation work for gluLookAt?

Comment: Try to set cameraPosition.x, cameraPosition.y and cameraPosition.z instead of those tree 0 (right column. Or -cameraPosition. But it's only suggestion, it might not work.

Comment: Tried, but does not seem to work.

Comment: @user5584 please specify what do you mean by rotation.

Comment: Yeah, just to be sure, at multipliing in a new matrix, from which side multiply with it? So curr = new*curr or curr = curr*new?

Comment: curr = curr * new normaly. But if matrices are transposed than it is curr = new * curr. But if you use opengl multiply it will solve it correctly so you will use curr = curr * new. If writing your own multiply use curr = new * curr

Comment: Ok, it seems to work, but I don't understand why I have to use it in this way. So the matrix is like You guys told me: the transponse of the one You wrote here. But! I have to add eye to look, so look+=eye, it seems the problem is caused by another part of my code :(

Comment: Yes you have to do it, if you want something like "fly camera". Look at point is point in world space where the camera is lookin at. Not in camera space, or camera direction. Wasn't that your mistake?

Comment: Yeah, the problem was the look vector was not the focus center, but focus direction. :D Sorry for troubling You guys with my clumsy myself.

Comment: No problem, this is fun. That's why we do it :]. Also please accept the answer, if you are satisfied and it solves your problem ;]

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what is wrong with your code, but it looks different to mine.
Here's what I've been using in my projects for the past few years.

```
    return new float4x4(
        Xax.X, Yax.X, Zax.X, 0,
        Xax.Y, Yax.Y, Zax.Y, 0,
        Xax.Z, Yax.Z, Zax.Z, 0,
        -float3.Dot(pos, Xax), -float3.Dot(pos, Yax), -float3.Dot(pos, Zax), 1
    );
```

I hope this helps somewhat.