# Converting Mouse Coords to 3d coords with Camera position

Tags: opengl, 3d, mouse, screen

So I've looked at all the answers I can possibly find, and nothing seems to fit what I need exactly (because im bad at math).

I'll explain what I have thus far:

- A camera with x,y,z, Pitch and Yaw float variables.

Scene is rendered like so:

```
glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -(player->cam->getCamY())); // Distance from the ground
glRotatef(player->cam->getPitch(), 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glRotatef(-(player->cam->getYaw()), 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glTranslatef(-(player->cam->getCamX()), 0.0, -(player->cam->getCamZ()));
```

(Pitch looks up and down, Yaw looks left and right - the getCam's just return value of x, y or z of the camera)

- A ray function already implemented - It shoots a ray straight out of the camera into whatever direction the camera is facing, and intersects with whatever tile is in the center of the screen.
- and this function that I copied from the internet:

```
vector3d GetMousePos3D(int x, int y)
{
GLint viewport[4];
GLdouble modelview[16];
GLdouble projection[16];
```

`GLfloat winX, winY, winZ;
GLdouble posX, posY, posZ;

glGetDoublev( GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview );
glGetDoublev( GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection );
glGetIntegerv( GL_VIEWPORT, viewport );

winX = (float)x;
winY = (float)viewport[3] - (float)y;
glReadPixels( x, int(winY), 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &winZ );

gluUnProject( winX, winY, winZ, modelview, projection, viewport, &posX, &posY, &posZ);

return vector3d(posX, posY, posZ);`

which, as you can probably tell, does not return the desired results because it doesn't interact with the camera. I have no idea how to do this.

Basically, if I can work out the mouse coordinates relative to the camera coordinates, then everything should work fine.

If you need any other information, just ask. This problem is causing me a lot of distress, and the math feels beyond me.

Comment: I dont see anything wrong as far as your loading the correct modelview and projection matrix and using gluUnproject the returned coordinate should be fine. anyway if you want to cast a ray you may want to use 0.0 and 1.0 for gluUnproject with winZ parameter instead of reading it from the depth buffer. I dont understand the part with "Basically, if I can work out the mouse coordinates relative to the camera coordinates, then everything should work fine."

Comment: Oh yes, my mistake. I feel stupid, the solution was actually quite simple. I spent like 8 hours today on this. Sigh.

Comment: possible duplicate of [converting a mouse click to a ray](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8974/converting-a-mouse-click-to-a-ray)